Scrap Network Tab Data using Python without selenium-wire
I want to scrap/fetch data from Network Tab using python. I don't want to use selenium-wire. Is there any alternative solution to achieve it ? I have tried with HTTP request  but it is not working at all.
 import requests


header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0'
}
response = requests.get("https://www.hotala.com/refine?search=Eatonville,%20Florida,%20USA&dateStart=2024-05-08&dateEnd=2024-05-09&order=1",headers=header)  # Replace with your URL

# Access network data
network_data = response.headers  # Example: request headers
print(network_data)

[
